# Given a list of strings, how can I check if those strings are in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I wanted to have the user input a list of strings, how could I check to see if those strings matched a list already defined? Here is what what i tried:

```
Cake = ["Flour", "Eggs", "Milk"]
Burger = ["Beef", "Buns", "Lettuce", "Cheese"]
Hot_Dog = ["Sausage", "Buns", "Ketchup", "Mustard"]
my_list = [Cake, Burger, Hot_Dog]
ingredients = input("I have: ")
if (ingredients == Hot_Dog or Burger or Cake):
    print(my_list)
else:
    print("Nothing here")
```

I know this is doesn't do what I want it to. My intent was for it to return what you can make from the ingredients the user had given. So if I input "Flour" "Eggs" and "Milk", it would print out "Cake"

Comment: `ingredients` isn't a list of strings, but a string.

Comment: Note: `if (ingredients == Hot_Dog or Burger or Cake):` is not doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: `Hot_Dog or Burger or Cake` is a logical `or` of three lists. Logical `or` treats its operands as boolean values: and empty list is `False`, a non-empty list is `True`. Since all three lists are not empty, they are all treated as `True`, and the `Hot_Dog` (the first of the three) is the value of the expression. `Hot_Dog` is in turn compared to `ingredients`, and since one is list and the other is a string, the answer is always negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to match ingredients and then print out the thing you can make with them, consider using dictionaries as your primary data structure. This makes the correspondence between ingredients list to actual names very easy to work with:

```
my_recipes = {
    'Cake':["Flour", "Eggs", "Milk"],
    'Burger':["Beef", "Buns", "Lettuce", "Cheese"],
    'Hot_Dog' : ["Sausage", "Buns", "Ketchup", "Mustard"],
}
```

these will make it easier to print out `'Cake'` if some ingredients match.

Then you can take some `input` and `split` (default, whitespace chars) it :

```
ingredients = input("I have: ").split()
```

and go through the recipes in the dictionary `my_recipes` to match them:

```
# 'k' is the key for the dictionary i.e: "Cake"
# and 'v' is the value for that key i.e: "["Flour", "Eggs", "Milk"]"
for k, v in my_recipes.items():
    # checks to see if all items in values 
    # are in the ingredients list
    if all(i in ingredients for i in v):
        # if they are, print out what can be made
        print("Can make {}".format(k))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you care only about the ingredients, not their order, use sets and set operations:

```
Cake = set(["Flour", "Eggs", "Milk"])
Burger = set(["Beef", "Buns", "Lettuce", "Cheese"])
Hot_Dog = set(["Sausage", "Buns", "Ketchup", "Mustard"])
my_list = [Cake, Burger, Hot_Dog]

ingredients = set(input("I have: ").split())

for food in my_list:
    if not(food - ingredients):
         print(food)
```

Incidentally, `food - ingredients` is a set of *missing* ingredients.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example about solving this one:

```
cake_ingredients = ["Flour", "Eggs", "Milk"]
burguer_ingredients = ["Beef", "Buns", "Lettuce", "Cheese"]
hot_dog_ingredients = ["Sausage", "Buns", "Ketchup", "Mustard"]

my_list = {
    'cake': cake_ingredients,
    'burguer': burguer_ingredients,
    'hot_dog': hot_dog_ingredients
}

ingredients = "FlOur    EGGs   MiLk"

for k, v in my_list.items():
    v = set([ing.lower() for ing in v])
    remaining_ingredients = (
        v - set([ing.lower() for ing in ingredients.split()]))
    if len(remaining_ingredients) == 0:
        print("You got enough ingredients to make a {0}".format(k))
    else:
        print("You'd still need {0} to make a {1}".format(
            ','.join(remaining_ingredients), k
        ))
```